# Space complexity of following equation

Tags: math, time-complexity

I am not able to figure out. space  complexity of one of my program. 
its coming out as follows but i am not sure if it is O(n ^3),  or O(n^4)

```
1*n  + 2*(n-1) + 3*(n-2) + ..+ (n-1) *(2) +  n *1
```

as I understand `1+ 2 + 3 + ....+ n = n*(n-1)/2`

and here we have  two of them , so i was wondering if it will be O(n^4)

Answer (score 0):

**It is O(n<sup>3</sup>).**

I have computed the first five elements of this sequence:

n=1 -> 1
n=2 -> 4
n=3 -> 10
n=4 -> 20
n=5 -> 35

[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences® (OEIS®)](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C10%2C20%2C35&language=english&go=Search) 
says that these are the Tetrahedral (or triangular pyramidal) numbers: `a(n) = C(n+2,3) = n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6`.

**Of course, this is not a proof.** You should check by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description) whether your sum does satisfies this relation.